# Is web to lead form data submits in encrypted form?

Tags: security, leads, web2lead, encryption

I want to know that when web to lead form is submitted into salesforce, if the data in that form is encrypted or not.

I want to know that how much security is applied on web to lead?

I want to submit the data in encrypted form. Is it possible?

If salesforce handles the security of web to lead the please provide me the official document link how they secure web to lead data?

I tried to find it in document but not able to get any thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use https, it's encrypted. Otherwise, it's not. The security is entirely up to you.

Comment: My web to lead form contains some confidential data (Health care and patient diagnose). So is this security enough for me or need more. If it is not enough then what can i do to increase the security? Please Help Me.

Comment: Is the website where your form resides secure? Is it authenticated?

Comment: It is a public website for Hospital. If any patient submit form from there, we want to be sure that his info is securely submits in salesforce

Comment: Yes. HTTPS encryption is considered secure enough for most purposes. Make your that your website is also encrypted with HTTPS, preferably all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the page that web-to-lead creates, you'll see that the form opens with

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

The **https** in the action URL means the posting of your data back to Salesforce will be done securely, over https. So yes, it's secure.